# how to access attribute of xml file in vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

```
<xml xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882"           
xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft- 
com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
- <s:Schema id="RowsetSchema">
- <s:ElementType name="row" content="eltOnly">
- <s:AttributeType name="EffectId" rs:number="1" rs:nullable="true" rs:maydefer="true" 
rs:writeunknown="true">
<s:datatype dt:type="int" dt:maxLength="4" rs:precision="10" rs:fixedlength="true" /> 
</s:AttributeType>
- <s:AttributeType name="EffectName" rs:number="2" rs:nullable="true"   
rs:maydefer="true" rs:writeunknown="true">
<s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:maxLength="255" /> 
</s:AttributeType>
<s:extends type="rs:rowbase" /> 
</s:ElementType>
</s:Schema>
- <rs:data>
<z:row EffectId="0" EffectName="No Effect or Stop" /> 
<z:row EffectId="1" EffectName="Flash" /> 
<z:row EffectId="2" EffectName="Reversal AND Flash" /> 
<z:row EffectId="3" EffectName="Laser" /> 
<z:row EffectId="4" EffectName="scroling" /> 
<z:row EffectId="23" EffectName="LONG_SENTENCE_scroling" /> 
<z:row EffectId="5" EffectName="To the left" /> 
<z:row EffectId="6" EffectName="To the Right" /> 
<z:row EffectId="7" EffectName="To the Up Side" /> 
<z:row EffectId="8" EffectName="To the Down Side" /> 
<z:row EffectId="9" EffectName="Scale Up" /> 
<z:row EffectId="10" EffectName="Up -- Middle - Down" /> 
<z:row EffectId="11" EffectName="Twist Left and Right" /> 
<z:row EffectId="12" EffectName="Module horizontal Blind" /> 
<z:row EffectId="13" EffectName="Move to Center" /> 
<z:row EffectId="14" EffectName="Left - Middle -- Right" /> 
<z:row EffectId="15" EffectName="Up - Middle -- Down" /> 
<z:row EffectId="16" EffectName="Expand to Left and Right" /> 
<z:row EffectId="17" EffectName="Expand to Up and Down" /> 
<z:row EffectId="18" EffectName="Laser Down" /> 
<z:row EffectId="19" EffectName="Blind" /> 
<z:row EffectId="20" EffectName="Left - Middle -- Right" /> 
<z:row EffectId="21" EffectName="Twist Up and Down" /> 
<z:row EffectId="22" EffectName="Module Vertical Blind" /> 
</rs:data>
</xml>
```

This is my Effect.xml file .I am using vb.net to access this xml file.
Actually i want to access effect name when i enter particular effect id.So that i will get attribute value of effect name when i give effect id as input value
How can i do using vb.net

Answer (score 1):

The `System.xml` namespace provides a host of features. I shall prefer XQuery as the first option for your needs. Refer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.aspx